# GraphViz dot file. Node as Chess order

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following graph (and accompanying dot file)

[image: there is original picture]

```
digraph G { 
  a -> c; 
  a -> d; 
  a -> q; 
  a -> x;
  a -> qp; 
}
```

I want to organize the nodes in the graph "chess style view", like this:
[image: Chess style]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how does Chess have anything to do with this?

Comment: I mean only style. Black white sequence but with nodes. For example I have 12 inline nodes, but better have 2 line instead 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what exactly your finally after, an other layout algorithm could work for you:

```
neato -Tpng yourgraph.gv
```

[image: neato output]

---

The [`unflatten`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf) utility may be a more appropriate solution in some cases:

```
unflatten -f -l 2 yourgraph.gv | dot -Tpng -o unflattened.png
```

[image: unflattened graph]

Comment: thx! unflatten - look good for me. But I can't compile it. What I do in comand line I write "C:\Graphviz Path\dot.exe" "C:\Windows\Temp\fileName" -Tsvg and in command line I have result. but with your advice I cant reach such result as yours.

Comment: Try something similar to this: `"C:\Graphviz Path\unflatten.exe" -f -l 2 "C:\Windows\Temp\fileName" | "C:\Graphviz Path\dot.exe" -Tsvg`

Comment: Thx this works. And we can add some attr [-Gaspect=1] "C:\Graphviz Path\unflatten.exe" -f -l 2 "C:\Windows\Temp\fileName" | "C:\Graphviz Path\dot.exe" -Tsvg -Gaspect=1